# How make a threading mechanism in C++?

Tags: c++, multithreading

I know there are some threading libraries for C++, like Pthread, Boost etc out there, but how are they working? There must be an implementation of the logic somewhere.

Let's say that I would like to write my own threading mechanism in C++, not using any library, how would I start? What should I have in mind when writing it?

Comment: I would personally be using C++11 and the `<thread>` header ;)

Comment: Do not deal with threads at low levels. Do not write your own library or threading mechanism as you call it. Unless of course you have a good notion of writing multi-threaded code and you are dealing with exceptional cases that you cannot handle with already written libraries.

Comment: What library does Java VM (HotSpot) which is based on C use?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'd directly call the underlying API calls in the operating system.  For example, [CreateThread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682453%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  Naturally, this is cumbersome and platform-specific, which is why we like to use portable C++ threading libraries...

Answer (score 3):

In C++98/03, there is no notion of a "thread", so the question cannot be answered within the language. In C++11, the answer is to use `<thread>`.

On the implementation side, threading is an operating system feature. The operating system already has to schedule multiple *processes* (i.e. separate programs), and a multi-threading OS adds to that the ability to schedule multiple *threads* within one process. A the very heart, the OS may or may not take advantage of having physically more than one CPU (though that also applies to simple multi-processing; and conversely you can schedule multiple threads on a single CPU). At the heart of the programming, you will need hardware support for synchronisation primitives like atomic read/writes and atomic compare-and-swap to implement correct memory access. (This is *not* needed for only multi-*processing*, because separate processes have distinct memory; although it *will* be needed by the OS itself if there are multiple physical CPUs in use.)

Answer (score 1):

You can't write your own threading mechanism, unless you mean pseudo-threads like co-routines and not actual concurrently executing threads. This is because the fundamental thread mechanism is defined by the kernel and you can't change it nor implement your own. Any library you write must fall back, eventually, to the operating system.

Comment: ...or whatever other OS you're running on. =)

Comment: My mistake, I thought he'd written he was running Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you need something which is able to run several threads.

If you are working on developing an operating system kernel on the bare metal, I think that current multi-core processors have only one core working after their power-on reset. Even the BIOS on most PCs probably keep only one core working (and the other cores idle). So you'll need to write (assembly, non-portable) code to start other cores.

And (as James reminded you), most of the time you are using some operating system kernel. For instance, on Linux (I don't know about Windows), threads are known by the kernel (because the tasks it is scheduling are threads) and they need to be initiated by the [Linux `clone(2)` system call](http://linux.die.net/man/2/clone).

Often, kernel threads are quite heavy, and the system has a library ([NPTL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Native_POSIX_Thread_Library) for Linux Posix threads) which may use fewer kernel threads than user threads (actually Linux NPTL is a 1:1 mapping between kernel and user threads, but on some other systems, like probably Solaris, things are different).